# Fix broken json

Tags: php, arrays, json

echo `$value` gives `{\"logo\":\"fffffff\"}`

this json was traveled through some function and now contains unwanted slashes.

what is the opposite function I should call to normalize it?

Like `unserialize` for `serialize`. I'm not sure which function added these slashes.

Comment: That will depend entirely on what the function was that escaped it.

Comment: I hope that's not due to magic_quotes being on...

Comment: Check whether the server you are using has `magic_quotes` enabled. If it does, you need to filter your input. (And possibly I'd recommend changing hosts, magic_quotes is long since deprecated.) For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: @nikc.org thanks for additional info.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Into which concrete problem did you run with your try? What's the code? Why did the json was messed up *specifically*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try stripslashes() on the json string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: addslashes the only opposite function for stripslashes?

Comment: addslashes() places slashes in front of quotes in a string. Why your string has those slashes can have several reasons: Your server has magic_quotes enabled or the string was processed by a function like mysql_real_escape_string(), ...